# Get data after sorting according to indirect mapped data

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Consider following models over `PostgreSQL` database.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jars
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Jar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

I want a list of `Foo` in order of number of `Jar`.

For Example, Consider an array of `Foo` objects

```
[f1, f2, f3]
```

Each `Foo` object contain following number of `Jar` objects

> f1 => 1 Jar objects
>
> f2 => 5 Jar objects
>
> f3 => 2 Jar objects

then desired order is

```
[f2, f3, f1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo.joins(bars: {cars: :jars}).group('foo.id, jars.id').order('COUNT(jars.id)')
```

To write a where clause on `Jar` model:

```
Foo.joins(bars: {cars: :jars}).where(jars: {name: 'I am jar'})
```

Comment: It needs few corrections, it should be `joins(bars: {cars: :jars}).group('foos.id,jars.id')`. Also it would be great if you could add a solution for writing where clause for jar model

Comment: @RohitJangid edited and added a form for querying `jars` table